# Logger is freezing during logger.info

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback, spring-logback, logback-classic

My background job is (regularly) getting stuck when calling log.info(...) with Logback:

```
"pool-5-thread-1" #30 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f11c4ff2000 nid=0x100 waiting on condition [0x00007f11bd21a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000db93e3a8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$FairSync)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:870)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1199)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$FairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:224)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:285)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.subAppend(OutputStreamAppender.java:217)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.append(OutputStreamAppender.java:103)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.doAppend(UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.java:88)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.spi.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:48)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.appendLoopOnAppenders(Logger.java:273)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.callAppenders(Logger.java:260)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:442)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:396)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.info(Logger.java:600)
    at com.website.configuration.BackgroundJobs.lambda$run$2(BackgroundJobs.java:410)
    at com.website.configuration.BackgroundJobs$$Lambda$85/1402118067.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:647)
    at com.website.configuration.BackgroundJobs.run(BackgroundJobs.java:396)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor59.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

It sits in this state and doesn't progress until I restart the server.

Any ideas why this might happen?

I'm using spring boot 1.3.1.RELEASE with org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.3.1.RELEASE which uses logback-classic-1.1.3.

And I'm defining my loggers in my @Controllers and @Configuration classes like so:

```
final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass().getName());
```

And here is another thread-dump showing the same issue, but this time log.info is being called from a different class:

```
"pool-5-thread-1" #30 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f96f5cdc800 nid=0x100 waiting on condition [0x00007f9737d66000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000db6501f0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$FairSync)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:870)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1199)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$FairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:224)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:285)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.subAppend(OutputStreamAppender.java:217)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.append(OutputStreamAppender.java:103)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.doAppend(UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.java:88)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.spi.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:48)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.appendLoopOnAppenders(Logger.java:273)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.callAppenders(Logger.java:260)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:442)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:396)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.info(Logger.java:600)
    at com.website.service.JobScheduler.scheduleJob(JobScheduler.java:55)
    at com.website.configuration.BackgroundJobs.lambda$run$2(BackgroundJobs.java:411)
    at com.website.configuration.BackgroundJobs$$Lambda$85/1061458720.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:647)
    at com.website.configuration.BackgroundJobs.run(BackgroundJobs.java:396)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the actual problem was that I was logging so much in parallel that the logger was waiting for all the other logs to be output so it could continue.

Have improved the situation by reducing the amount of logging I'm doing.

And will later investigate asynchronous logging libraries (i.e. loggers that don't block).